# Org-babel-execute-src-block: Wrong type argument: listp, "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"

Tags: emacs

In an org file, C-c C-c in the following block

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
#+end_src
```

I get an error, in the echo area it displays: wrong type argument : listp, as shown in the title of the question.

But C-h v package-archives RET shows that the code is actually executed, I also tried something like

```
#+begin src emacs-lisp
(+ 1 1)
#+end src
```

and it runs correctly, so only when the code contains a associate list the problem persist, I've also tried with emacs -Q and only load the org-babel and ob-emacs-lisp lib, it behaves the same.

Comment: [This answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10242/11) might help. org-mode is a bit picky about values returned by code blocks. In particular, it seems like it doesn't like improper lists.

Comment: @legoscia Already checked that, does not solve the problem, I tried with emacs -Q and load org and org-babel, this time even the (+ 1 1) code does not works, really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Actually update org-mode to the newest version solve the problem, just make sure you delete /usr/local/share/emacs/lisp/org and install via package-install.